# Requirements for elements in std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

```
std::unordered_set<my_type> my_set;
```

Which requirements must my_type fulfill here? (Besides a specialization for std::hash)

Comment: You can just look this up in n3337 [unord.req] 23.2.5. Find n3337 on [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/) page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a specialization for std::hash, and you need an operator == defined to handle hash collisions.

EDIT: You should also make sure your type has a copy constructor (or let the compiler generate one for you) because STL containers have value semantics.

EDIT2: as an example of how to do this, you can check out [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672557/193789).

Comment: What about move/copy constructors and assignment operators?

Comment: Yeah you'll probably need those too. But more directly, the type must be hashable and equality comparable.

Comment: So move doesn't do the job? (I kind of hoped it would, since vector etc. go fine with it..)

Comment: Moving would do the job if you are moving the object into the container. However, moving isn't a requirement because if the object cannot be moved, but can still be copied, then you can use it in the container.

Comment: I meant no copy but only move. ;)

Comment: Oh! Well it looks like unordered_set has an insert( ) overload for rvalues. So moving instead of copying should be okay. Test it!

Comment: Well, I could've tested it before, I'm asking here to be sure it is compliant.

Comment: @cooky451 : If your type is not copyable then the `std::unordered_set<>` instance will also not be copyable. I.e., move-only is fine as long as you're okay with the `std::unordered_set<>` instance also being move-only.

Comment: -1: "You should also make sure your type has a copy constructor" C++11 containers are moveable as well. And containers don't *have* to be copyable; they're only copyable if the contents are copyable.

Comment: Also -1:  Exactly *which* of move constructor, copy constructor, move assignment, and copy assignment are needed are *exactly* what I was looking for!