# How to use std::unordered_set in C++?

Tags: c++, hash

I picked the concepts of hash tables in Java, so I was aware that for a generic "hash set" container to work for custom classes, one must provide definition for a hash function and an corresponding equality function.

In Java, this would mean overriding method

```
int hashCode()
```

and

```
boolean equals (Object o)
```

.

I was expecting the same logic in c++'s STL, but was having trouble understanding the syntax. Specifically, std::unordered_set<> accepts 5 template arguments (can you believe that?), which looks like a monster and makes my head spin.

So I would be appreciate it if one could give a simple example for the current toy class:

```
class Some{
public :
int a;
};
```

Of which  the hash function simply returns the value of a, and the equality test functions returns true iff the values of member 'a' are the same.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: `I picked the concepts of hash tables in Java [...] I was expecting the same logic in c++'s STL` Please keep in mind that Java and C++ are different languages that require different mindsets.

Comment: `Key`, `Hash`, `KeyEqual` and `Allocator` are 4 parameters, not 5.

Comment: Java claims itself to be a OO Language, yet those programmers that built Unix operating system have long been adopting the notion of OOP in writing kernel code. If you wish, you could do OOP using assembly.  This is the 'logic' I was mentioning, not syntax:) Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Fair enough. Neither Java nor C++ resemble what Alan Kay had in mind when he invented object-orientation, by the way.

Comment: Since I dunno who Alan Kay actually is I did a little Googling and learned even more:) Thanks! Speaking of C++ and Java, I see no essential difference between them except for garbage collection and the "Interface" idea instead of multiple inheritance. The rest is all about syntax. Of course c++ stresses run-time performance while Java is designed to approach other problems. Anyway, I don't follow your point here. Could you gimme a hint?

Comment: The proper response to your comment, @Diaz, could fill a 100-page book. Such a shame there's a character limit here

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I find the accept answer perfectly proper, which looks great on this webpage. I am looking forward to see your 100-page book published:)

Comment: @DeadMG In case I see it wrong... you seem to have a problem with C++? Of course programming in Java is 'easier', but consider this: buying pre-cooked food is easier than buying fresh materials and cooking them yourself. However, anyone can go get pre-cooked food, which look all them same, as provided. Do you find this food decent or remarkable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step 1: Overload `operator==` for your type:

```
bool operator==(const Some& x, const Some& y)
{
    return x.a == y.a;
}
```

Step 2: Specialize `std::hash` for your type:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Some>
    {
        typedef Some argument_type;
        typedef size_t result_type;

        size_t operator()(const Some& x) const
        {
            return x.a;
        }
    };
}
```

Step 3: A simple test:

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Some> test;
    test.insert(Some{42});
}
```

Step 4: Profit!

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a compiler, so there might be errors, but it should be something similar to:

```
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct hash<Some>
  {
    typedef Some argument_type;
    typedef std::size_t  result_type;

    result_type operator()(const Some & t) const
    {
       return t.a;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about `argument_type` and `result_type`! Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: As I see it, you are taking advantage of the notion that std::unsorted_set by default looks for std::hash<class T> as the function object used to calculate a hash value out of a given object.

Comment: I did pretty much the same, except that I created my own class (instead of std::hash<>), and specified it to be the Hasher when declaring my container. The compiler complained about "invalid operands to binary expression" and I was out of ideas:(

Comment: @Diaz That is correct. You could also parameterize `std::unordered_set` with different hash and equality functors, but then the types become very long and unreadable.

Comment: @Diaz Did you provide an equality functor, or overload `operator==`?

Comment: @FredOverflow No, I was being stupid. LOL. Thanks so much for your help.