# What should hash for a custom datatype return in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to use a data type of mine in an `unordered_set`. It didn't work but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22672255/8076979) helped to understand what I needed to do.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079061/8076979) however confused me to what exactly I should put in the hash struct.
Should my hash now return `x.name.size()` or rather `x.hash`?

My data type:

```
struct State {
  std::string name;
  std::size_t hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(name);

  bool operator==(const State &rhs) const;
  bool operator!=(const State &rhs) const;
  };
```

Should I use A or B ?

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<State>{

  typedef State argument_type;
  typedef std::size_t  result_type;

  size_t operator()(const foundation::State& x) const{
    // A.) return x.name.size();
    // B.) return x.hash;
  }
};
}
```

Comment: `return x.hash;` will work, but beware that storing the hash as a member is a trade-off. You need explicitly refresh that hash every time the state of `State` changes. Technically `return x.name.size();` would also work, but it would probably result in very poor performances in your set.

Comment: your hash is the lenght of the string in any case and you are asking wether to store it as member or recompute it on every call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary function of a hash function is to be a good proxy whether two objects are possibly the same or definitely different.

If you return `x.name.size()`, State objects with the same amount of letters will have the same hash code. This will result in lots of collisions if you stick these objects in an unordered_set. That means that it will have to rely on relatively expensive comparisons to determine whether two objects are, in fact, the same.

If you return `x.hash` instead (which ought to be the hash of `x.name` (which hopefully never changes)), any difference in the name will cause a wildly different hash value. Depending on the hash function used, two different objects will only have a 1 in 2^128 (or 1 in 2^64 on a 32bit system) chance of colliding. Your unordered_set will thus very likely be able to spread results uniformly and get you closer to that magical O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 2):

If you return `x.name.size()` as hash for your object, you are saying two things essentially:

- You want objects with `name` as "abc", "def", "123" all to have the same hash.
- You want no other field to participate as a contributor to hash code of your objects.

The first point here is problematic from a performance perspective. It will result in a very poor spread of distinct objects in the hash table since you are using lengths rather than content of the name.

The second implication may or may not have a noticeable impact but with the information given it is not certain which direction it will go.

Answer (score 2):

You should return something consistent with your `==`.

I'm going to assume that you've defined it as

```
bool State::operator==(const State &rhs) const
{
    return (name == rhs.name);
}
```

In which case it's most naturally

```
size_t std::hash<foundation::State>::operator()(const foundation::State& x) const {
    return std::hash<std::string>{}(x.name);
}
```

If you have more members participating in `==`, they should also participate in `std::hash`. There are many strategies for combining hashes.

I suggest *not* having a data member `std::size_t hash`.